# How to check if user input is less than max value in Angular 2

Tags: angular, input, range, conditional-statements, minimum

I want to create a range filter in Angular. The user should not be able to enter a minimum value, which is smaller than the maximum input value.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="from" [placeholder]="Minimum" />

<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="to" [placeholder]="Maximum" />
```

I'm not sure what to do. I guess I have to create two variables in the .ts-file (minValue and maxValue). And then check directly in the HTML with *ngIf, if the minValue is smaller than the maxValue and then send an error.

Does someone has an idea how to solve it properly? Thank you very much

Comment: Minimum value can be anything and maximum value should not be less than minimum input value right? is that what your question?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set Validator on change of "from" formControl

Try like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    ...
    this.contactForm.get("from").valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      this.contactForm.get("to").setValidators(Validators.min(val));
    });
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-reactive-form-l82s2v)**

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="frmGrp">
    <input type="number" formControlName="fromValue" [min]="toCtrl.value" [value]="getMinValue()">
    <input type="number" formControlName="toValue">
</form>
```

**Component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  frmGrp: FormGroup;
  fromCtrl: AbstractControl;
  toCtrl: AbstractControl;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.frmGrp = this.fb.group({
      fromValue: [0],
      toValue: [0]
    });

    this.fromCtrl = this.frmGrp.get('fromValue') as FormControl;
    this.toCtrl = this.frmGrp.get('toValue') as FormControl;
  }

  getMinValue() {
    if (this.toCtrl.value > this.fromCtrl.value) {
      this.fromCtrl.setValue(this.toCtrl.value);
    }
    return this.fromCtrl.value;
  }
}
```

Here is the working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-juxvyu)